# How to create second level navigation using the same component in Angular

Tags: angular, routes, navigation

I have this kind of situation. In routing module, I have declared several routes that should work with the same component. These are /start, /sport, /informative, /economics and so on. And then they have children such as /economics/industry, /economics/tourism and so on. Only /start doesn't have any children. It shows all the stories. But they are all working with the same component and my idea is to display second line navigation when the the route isn't /start. On every route such as /sport, /informative and so on, there should be displayed all the stories related to these categories. And then children routes should further filter the scope of stories to the level of subcategories such as tourism or industry. How to achieve this kind of routing? I tried to put two router outlets, one on first line navigation and one on the second line of navigation. First line works fine, filters the stories by category and displays navbar with the subcategories related to the active category. But here things get tricky. When I click on any of the subcategories in the second level navigation, it renders second line navbar again without further filtering of the stories. How to solve this issue without using parameters, since I'd like even further to filter the scope of stories when keyword is provided. That's why I'm not using parameter in the route for subcategory. Just to clarify, all the mentioned routes should use one single component - StoriesComponent.